# Why an "Undefined offset" throws an exception in one machine, but shows a notice in another?

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, phpunit

I am getting different results on my local machine than on Travis for a simple test.

Here is the test:

```
class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testArrayKeyUndefined(): void
    {
        $a = [1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c'];
        $this->assertEquals('a', $a[1]);
        $this->assertEquals('c', $a[3]);
        $this->expectException(\ErrorException::class);
        $b = $a[99];
    }
}
```

on my local machine, the test passes. On Travis (with PHP 7.2 and 7.3), it does not:

> FooTest::testArrayKeyUndefined
>   Undefined offset: 99

My phpunit.xml.dist file includes this

```
<phpunit
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    bootstrap="./src/lib/bootstrap.php"
>
```

I am actually using simple-phpunit with Symfony 5. This loads PHPUnit 8.3.5

Other tests that expect *real* exceptions are working as expected. Only the `\ErrorException` is not working at Travis (but still working on my local machine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it works in your dev machine at all, since for me the default behaviour is what you get on our server.

Something in your local code is changing the error handler, so PHPUnit's error handler is being overridden.

Basically, PHPUnit converts the `E_NOTICE` to a `PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Notice`, and you are asserting that you'll get an `\ErrorException`. Which only works in your dev machine because of that error handler change.

Changing your code to this works for me:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Notice;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class RandomTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testNoticeToException(): void
    {
        $this->expectException(Notice::class);
        trigger_error('Notice Issued');

    }
}
```

You can also use this, which is equivalent:

```
$a = [1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c'];
$this->expectNotice();
$b = $a[99];
```

*Why* are you getting an `ErrorException` in your local machine... I'm not sure. You'll need to look for something that executes `set_error_handler()`.

I notice that in your configuration you are loading `lib/bootstrap.php`, which is not in the default Symfony path. I'd start checking from that point forward.

Comment: I am running my local machine in `dev` environment and `debug` is `true`. There are only a few additional dependencies in `dev`: Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class; Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class; Elao\WebProfilerExtraBundle\WebProfilerExtraBundle::class; Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class; I am running my local environment with MAMP Pro. Shouldn't the phpunit config convert the NOTICE into an EXCEPTION?

Comment: what does `convertNoticesToExceptions="true"` do then? I assumed that was exactly what it did. Thank you btw, for your help!

Comment: additional info, when I run my tests on my local machine, the tests all run and finish and the before the deprecations are listed I get `THE ERROR HANDLER HAS CHANGED!` printed.  I've looked into this also and cannot figure out the answer. perhaps they are related.

Comment: running your new test, I get `Failed asserting that exception of type "ErrorException" matches expected exception "PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Notice". Message was: "User Notice: Notice Issued"` So on my local machine it is converting notices to `ErrorException` instead of `Notice`. This brings me back to the above comment regarding `THE ERROR HANDLER HAS CHANGED!` perhaps that is the reason. Although I've not configured any error handler myself.

Comment: Which again brings me to to the first point I made. It's was working correctly in your remote server, but something is amiss in your local setup. There is an error handler messing with the regular behaviour. What? Impossible to guess with what we have here. Anything that calls `set_error_handler` either in your tests, or in the code your tests use.

Comment: indeed that was the clue to finding the right answer. I generated a new config and it suggested pointing to `vendor/autoload` and doing so essentially solved the problem. Notices are now being converted properly. Thank you so much for your help!